# Do cosmos db index resides in a logical partition or in physical one?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

If I have 'id' field specified as the partition key, does this mean that any indexes on other fields are useless? Because if I search by some other field, say 'name', for which I have an index, that would still mean that db engine would need to go through all index instances for each logical partition.

Or do logical partitions within a physical partition share a single index instance. In that case even if have partition key set to 'id', indexes on other fields will increase performance of read queries?

Example:

Document structure:

```
{
  id: string
  name: string
}
```

Partition Key = "/id"

Query:

```
SELECT * from c
WHERE c.name = "John"
```

Will that query use index on field 'name'? (assuming indexing policy is in it's default state with automatic indexing of all fields)

More specifically, will it be a single index lookup assuming all logical partitions are within a single physical partition? Or will it need to make n index lookups where n is number of logical partitions?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but... why would you assume an index is *useless*? They're not useless. Please edit to show your code/query/etc and what specific issue you're having - tl;dr create a [mcve]. As written, this question is more about the inner workings of Cosmos DB, or general information-gathering about queries and indexes... and not a programming question.

Comment: Because if index is created for each logical partition and number of logical partitions equals to number of items in a container. Would not that mean that we need to go through all that indexes to find an item? If index is shared among all logical portions within a physical one it is not going to be useless. That is my

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a million logical partitions in a single physical partition CosmosDB certainly doesn't create 1 million index structures and fan your query out on non partition key properties across those.

You get a single inverted index per physical partition.

(Or in the case of a shared throughput database a single inverted index per collection per physical partition.)

Note "indexes on other fields" don't create separate indexes even in APIs like Mongo API which give the impression of this.

You just control the paths that are contained in the inverted index.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I hope it is indeed as you say!

Comment: It definitely is - though I couldn't find any documentation that states this from a very quick Google. But you should be able to see this by setting up a test very easily (create a new collection partitioned on `_id` and wildcard indexing and insert a few hundred thousand documents - then query on property `foo` and look at the query stats and RU cost)

Comment: Yeah, I will certainly do some tests here, but I also could not find any docs that confirms this assumption that a single index structure is shared by all logical partitions within a physical one.